# Android Studio: Java not found

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to install Android Studio on my Macbook Pro running OSX Yosemite. Every time I try to open the Android Studio application, I get an error that says:

> Java not found
>
> Android Studio was unable to find a valid JVM.

I know that I have Java installed, and when I go into Terminal and do java -version, I get:

> java version "1.8.0_20"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

How can I address this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369269/android-studio-was-unable-to-find-a-valid-jvm-related-to-mac-os

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have only installed a JRE. In order to run Android Studio needs Java SE Development Kit.

You can get it here.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

On a windows machine this occurs when the PATH in your system variables have the wrong reference. 
I had this error because I referenced a Java 32 bit version on a 64 bit computer.

I think it will help to change this. But i dont know how on a mac.