# Android Studio was unable to find a valid JVM

Tags: java, android-studio, jvm, adt

"Android Studio was unable to find a valid JVM"
I use Mac OS Yosemite.

The official statement is:
"Please note: Do not edit Info.plist to pick a different version. That will break not only the application signature, but also future patch updates to your installation."

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Already answered over here **[Android Studio was unable to find a valid Jvm (Related to MAC OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369269/android-studio-was-unable-to-find-a-valid-jvm-related-to-mac-os)**

Note that this last variable allows you to for example run Android Studio with Java 7 on OSX (which normally picks Java 6 from the version specified in Info.plist):

$ export STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk

$ open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app

Worked for me