# Java Not Found. Android Studio was unable to find a valid JVM. (On Mac OS)

Tags: java, android, macos, sdk

I understand that this top has had several other posts but each were flooded and saturated with very different methods and now that it has been a month or so since the last one and now with then Android Studio 1.0.1 i would like to see if anyone could help me.

When ever i run the application after installing and moving it to my applications folder- i get the following message---- "Java Not Found. Android Studio was unable to find a valid JVM."

I have tried youtube and google and even stack for solutions and have yet to find a straight forward solutions. I tried to read the instructions on the Android Dev site but i don't exactly understand them.

If anyone has a solution to this issue, i'd really appreciate it!

Thank you guys!

Comment: So, do you have a Java installation on your mac?

Comment: Did you checked that?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369269/android-studio-was-unable-to-find-a-valid-jvm-related-to-mac-os

Comment: i do have java installed and i have checked the other questions- the issue is that the answers to the other questions are so vast and different i was looking for a more recent and up to date one because those were months old :/

Answer (score 7):

[Mac OSX JDK Selection instructions](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk) worked on my Mac (Yosemite & Java 8):

> $ export STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
>   $ open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app

You can [find out the correct jdk path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15826712/1097104) for export: `/usr/libexec/java_home`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when running the Android Studio installer.
This one actually solved it for me:

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572

It seems studio is looking for version 1.6 (JavaForOSX2014-001.dmg).
Both, 1.6 version from Apple site and other one from Oracle, can be installed on a single system as they are placed in different folders.