# Android Studio Can not find JVM

Tags: java, android

Could someone please explain to me how i am supposed to fix the issue with Android Studio 1.0.1 where it states it can't find my JVM? I know the site says this is the solution but i can't understand what i am supposed to do with the information given on the site?
This is the direct link to the site

*****http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration*****

[image]

Comment: How would i check and go about getting the correct API? Thank you for your help!

Comment: i'm using my macbook pro

Comment: The issue isn't an emulator i don't think- I'm just trying to run the android studio compiler

Answer (score 0):

There is a question that addresses this issue already, with lots of information/answers here: [Android Studio - No JVM Installation found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898684/android-studio-no-jvm-installation-found) , assuming that your error is the same as the error listed in the StackOverflow post that is linked

Comment: I have tried looking at that but there were so many answers i wasn't able to figure it out. That's why i narrowed my question down to this specific site.

Comment: @user3681591 OK. What is the exact error it is giving you? Is the error the same as the one in the linked post? And what OS are you using? Windows/Mac/Linux

Comment: I installed the latest java 8 and then i downloaded the new Android studio after using Eclipse and the android plug ins, but when i downloaded the new Android Studio and attempted to run in (on Mac OS) it pops up a message "Java Not Found- Android Studio was unable to find a valid JVM"- the official android site says that this webpage is the solution but i don't understand or really even see any instructions- please help and thanks!

Comment: @user3681591 So, because there is no "valid JVM" Android Studio won't start up. I have not had experience with this problem. Personally, I would try to uninstall & delete/reinstall all of Android Studio. However, this site seems to do the trick [Link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk) And from reading the comments in this post here [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369269/android-studio-was-unable-to-find-a-valid-jvm-related-to-mac-os) it looks like there are two different JDK's that need to be installed (Java SE Dev Kit 8 and Java Version 8)