# "The package filter removed all packages" error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am stuck on this error:

> Android Studio The package filter removed all packages

The closest question I've found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334086/android-studio-not-letting-me-install-the-android-sdk-platform), but unfortunately that didn't help.

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image]

I have an active internet connection that works so I'm stuck trying to figure out why Android Studio thinks there is no connection. I've searched around for the mentioned 'filters' but I haven't found anything on that subject.

Also, I have the following SDK Platforms & Tools installed:

[image]

[image]

Last but not least, my build Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "company.MyApp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':comcrashlyticssdkandroid_crashlytics')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}
```

What's something to check next in order to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

The backstory:

This is an SVN project originally built in eclipse and we're currently migrating it over to Android Studio. Upon Android Studio upgrades I started experiencing this issue and NOTHING would get me through it. Here's what I tried:

- Updating SDK's via SDK manager
- Changing *Build Tools* version in Project Manager
- `./android update sdk --no-ui` in terminal (mac osx)
- uninstall / reinstall

SAME ISSUES - Build tools *install failed*

## Solution

So I tossed the svn folder and download a new one. Something during that process cleared everything up. That doesn't really solve the issue but perhaps this will help someone out. *Good Luck*