# Just opening Android Studio from application folder giving "Android Studio quit unexpectedly"

Tags: java, android, macos, osx-yosemite

I installed JDK 8 and JRE 8 and downloaded Android Studio in my Mac (Yosemite, 10.10). I moved the android studio icon to the application folder, as instructed. When I try to open Android Studio, it gives me a "Android Studio quit unexpectedly" error message. I have re-downloaded the studio yet the same error messages pops up. Is there something wrong that I am doing?

Comment: Check out : https://teamtreehouse.com/library/build-an-android-app/getting-started-with-android/setting-up-an-android-development-environment-for-mac

Comment: Do you mean, you downloaded JRE separately?

Comment: related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369269/android-studio-was-unable-to-find-a-valid-jvm-related-to-mac-os

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing the info.plist file inside android studio package worked for me. I changed JVM version from 1.6* to 1.8*.