# Android Studio was unable to find a valid JVM Android Studio 1.2 OSX

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, jvm

I have a new OSX machine. I just installed Android Studio 1.2 but I am greeted with a popup that no JVM is installed.

I installed Java 8 u45 from Oracles site. So that should suffice as the JVM. I want to make clear that I looked here first:

[Android Studio was unable to find a valid Jvm (Related to MAC OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369269/android-studio-was-unable-to-find-a-valid-jvm-related-to-mac-os/27370525#27370525)

As the answer in that question says, "This is fixed in Android Studio 1.1 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82378"

The popup links me to an [Apple page to download Java 6](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). I don't want Java 6 on my machine and it is not supposed to be needed as of AS 1.1/1.2.

I installed Java 8, it just seems like Android Studio 1.2 can't find it. What to do?

Comment: If you are having path of JDK bin as environment variables or something (I use windows), then don't give the full path to bin. Only give the path upto JDK folder

Comment: Hmm... I installed Java on the computer and thought that was enough. I installed JDK 8 and that did the trick. I'm aware that I need a JDK to develop, it's just that the error message specifically said JVM, so I thought installing Java should take care of that. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I installed Java on the computer and thought that was enough. I installed JDK 8 and that did the trick. I'm aware that I need a JDK to develop, it's just that the error message specifically said JVM, so I thought installing Java should take care of that. Oh well.