# MacOS Cannot start android studio, java update required

Tags: java, android-studio

Android Studio on my Mac can not start.

A Java Update dialog is shown when I open the Android Studio app.
The dialog's content is:

> Java version: 1.6.0_51-b11-457 which is installed on your Mac is obsolete.
> Would you like to update Java?

I pressed the update button, the Java Update dialog disappeared, but nothing happens after that.

When I run command `java -version` on terminal. The result is:

> java version "1.8.0_92"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

I had installed java via `brew cask install java` and Android Studio via `brew cask install android-studio`

My MacOS version is: `OS X El Capitan 10.11.5`

The Android Studio version is `2.1.1.0,143.2821654` as I look at homebrew cask's installation folder `/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/android-studio/2.1.1.0,143.2821654/`'s name

This problem has already token takes me hours of googling, but there is still no way to continue. Finally, I decided to go to StackOverflow :(.

Could anyone tell me how should I do to use Android Studio?

Many thanks,

Comment: What does your JAVA_HOME point to? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6588390/1793718 You should see this similar post http://stackoverflow.com/a/27369596/1793718 What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @Lucky I edited my post to add Android Studio version. It is the latest version from homebrew-cask.

There is no export of JAVA_HOME, so I think it be empty
After set JAVA_HOME to `"$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"`, there is still error of obsoleted java

Comment: You must be having separate versions of JDK & JRE.
How did you install Java on your MAC at first?
Is it a pre-installed version or you installed it from Oracle installer?

Comment: I installed by `brew cask install java`

Comment: I think if you don't want to manage multiple Java versions you should install JDK directly with the installer provided by Oracle, and try reinstalling the Android studio.

Comment: I will consider that.

Until now, I have never installed anything from .pkg file. All apps in my Mac were installed using `brew`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio was unable to find a valid Jvm (Related to MAC OS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369269/android-studio-was-unable-to-find-a-valid-jvm-related-to-mac-os)

Answer (score 2):

Follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369269/android-studio-was-unable-to-find-a-valid-jvm-related-to-mac-os/27369596#27369596), when the Java Update dialog shows, right click to its icon under docker bar > Options > Show in finder

Open package content of `Android Studio.app` to edit `info.plist`.
Change `JVMOptions->JVMVersion` from `1.6*,1.7+` to `1.6+,1.7+`.

Now it works