# Gradle 3.3 Error Need Java 7 or Later Unsolved

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.1

i just imported some project that i bought from my friend.
Once i import it to Android Studio 2.1.2 i just get this messages
"Error:Gradle 3.3 requires Java 7 or later to run. You are currently using Java 6."

I have install Java 7 and 8 in my mac. I have change the directory in Default Project Structure, but still that messages always appear and i can't do anything with the code.

Please master, help me.

Comment: A couple of questions:
1) Did you add Java 7 to the Environment PATH.
2) When you create a new project, does it work fine?

Comment: Is $JAVA_HOME path true?

Comment: In case, the problem is with the imported project only, can you paste the gradle info here ?

Comment: @SuhaylSH 1) Where's the environment path you mean buddy? 2) this project is from my friend and it's working well on his PC.

Comment: How to check the path @mustafacil?

Comment: Did you mean the console Log? @SuhaylSH

Comment: This may help you: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369269/android-studio-was-unable-to-find-a-valid-jvm-related-to-mac-os

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue, but I needed to keep java 6 for macOS legacy reasons (as I commented on Shubhendu's post).  So I ended up downloading java 8 jdk found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

and on android studio 3.3 at least here is the rough path I took:

I right clicked project -> open module settings -> sdk location -> uncheck use embedded jdk -> added path to new 1.8 jdk which for me it was

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home

[image: adding java 8 idk to studio 3.3 project]

Answer (score 1):

Use this path in the Default Project Structure by using the browse option go up to this Directory named home.

**/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home**

May it works for you.

Comment: Yes i also use that path. But still that message appear

Comment: Just Clean Your project and try to rebuild it.

Comment: Still, android studio said i just using Java 6

Answer (score 1):

Deleting java 6 worked for me:

Run below command on your mac terminal:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk`

[image]

Comment: what if you need java 6 for legacy reasons? certain macOS version sadly requires this..

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S` to reach `Project Structure` window. Change Project SDK 
[image]